# Dynamic filter in iris

Tags: shiny, filtering

I have created two different filters and I will like to develop a dynamic filter.
If the dataset doesn't have one value the second/first filter must eliminate the other value from the filter. (It is a circular approach, maybe it is better hierarchical)
Do I need to use an observeEvent? But where?

For example, I have used the iris dataset and if I select Species setosa I will like to see only 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)


shinyUI (fluidPage(
  navbarPage("My Application",

             tabPanel("First",
                      tabPanel("Per Famiglia Prodotto",
                               selectInput("Specie", "Per specie", choices = unique(iris$Species)),
                               
                               tabPanel("Classe2",
                                        selectInput("classe2", "Classe2", choices = unique(iris$Petal.Width)),
                                        
  
                               )
                      )
             )
  )
)
)



shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {
    iris

    

classe <- reactive({
filter(iris, iris$Species == input$classe)})

observeEvent(classe(), {
  choices <- unique(classe()$Petal.Width)
  updateSelectInput(inputId = "classe2", choices = choices) 
})
   classe2 <- reactive({
     req(input$classe2)
     filter(Dato, Petal.Width == input$classe2)
   })
```

Comment: Try `updateSelectInput()` on the server side.

Comment: Where can I add? I have try a code but it's work I had update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("My Application",
             tabPanel("First",
                      selectInput("Specie", "Per specie", choices = unique(iris$Species)),
                      selectInput("classe2", "Classe2", choices = unique(iris$Petal.Width)),
                      DTOutput("t1")
             )
  )
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {
  
    classe <- reactive({dplyr::filter(iris, iris$Species == input$Specie)})
    
    observeEvent(classe(), {
      choices <- unique(classe()$Petal.Width)
      updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "classe2", choices = choices) 
    })
    
    classe2 <- reactive({
      req(input$classe2)
      filter(classe(), Petal.Width == input$classe2)
    })
    output$t1 <- renderDT(classe2())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```